# how to add tensor size pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a problem while working on PyTorch.

I'm trying to increase tensor size from `[1,97,1]` to `[1,97,2]`. How can I add "1" in tensor size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad)

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
a = torch.empty((1,97,1))

a = F.pad(input=a, pad=(0,1))     # pad = (padding_left,padding_right)

print(a.shape)
>>> torch.Size([1, 97, 2])
```

it will pad `0` constant by default at right sight.